# Что такое трейт?

Tags: терминология, rust

Не совсем понимаю, что есть "трейт". Есть бэкграунд из ООП, но там я с таким понятием не встречался.

Интересует понятие трейта в целом, и в частности (если есть какие-то особенности, о которых нужно знать), для языка Rust.

Ищу объяснение простым языком. Очень желательно с примерами применения и реализации.

Comment: а чем непонятно пояснение и справки?

Comment: @Grundy непонятна концепция. Есть понимание интерфейсов, типов, классов (и т.п.). Может быть понятие трейта можно как-то переложить на какое-то из этих понятий?

Comment: [Traits are similar to a feature often called interfaces in other languages, although with some differences.](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Конечно, советую первоисточник: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html . Если простыми словами, то trait (англ. черта, признак, умение) -- определяет функциональность, которую имеет конкретный тип и которую он может иметь совместно с другими типами.

Из личного опыта, `trait` в Rust похож на `@protocol` в Objective-C. А в документации так и сказано, что trait похож на interface в других языках.

Самый простой пример:

```
#![allow(unused)]
trait Обзор {
    fn обзор(&self) -> String;
}

struct Книга {
    автор :  String,
    название : String,
    содержание : String,
}

impl Обзор for Книга {
    fn обзор(&self) -> String {
        format!("{}, {}", self.название, self.автор)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let повесть = Книга {
        автор : "Вася".to_string(), 
        название : "Мемуары".to_string(), 
        содержание: "Было так...".to_string()};
    println!("{}", &повесть.обзор());
}
```

Печатает на выходе: Мемуары, Вася

Допустим, в какой-то момент вы создали какой-либо другой тип (`Инструкция`, `СМС`, `Карта`, `Газета`). Любой из них может иметь данное "умение".

```
impl Обзор for Инструкция {};
impl Обзор for СМС {};
impl Обзор for Карта {};
impl Обзор for Газета {};
```

Более того, в Rust есть концепция `lifetime` ("срок жизни"), которую я не встречал ни в каких других языках (может она и есть где-то). Нет в Rust одной важной черты классического ООП -- в нём нет наследования! Т.е. никакой связи "предок-потомок". Всё определяется через `trait`s.

Однако, можно создавать наборы из различных "умений", добавляя нечто новое. Вот пример из реальной жизни:

```
pub trait ID3D12Debug5_Impl: Sized + ID3D12Debug_Impl + ID3D12Debug3_Impl + ID3D12Debug4_Impl {
    fn SetEnableAutoName(&self, enable: BOOL);
}
```

Это вроде, как бы похоже на некое "наследование" (inheritance). Но, опять же, собственно такого понятия в Rust нет.

Очень (может быть, даже самый важный момент, точки зрения использования) -- это trait objects, "объекты с умениями". https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/trait-object.html

```
// К коду выше...
fn напечатать_обзор(a: &dyn Обзор) {
    println!("{}", a.обзор());
}

напечатать_обзор(&повесть); // Печатает: Мемуары, Вася

// А также, если такие объекты определены:
напечатать_обзор(&инструкция);
напечатать_обзор(&смс);
напечатать_обзор(&карта);
напечатать_обзор(&газета);
```

Добавление о "сверх способностях" (supertraits). С помощью чего достигается некое подобие наследования.

```
trait Рекомендация {
    fn рекомендация(&self) -> String;
}

trait ОбзорДляЦенителей: Обзор + Рекомендация {
    fn ценный_обзор(&self) -> String;
}
```

Далее, как пример, использование:

```
struct Фолиант {}

impl Обзор for Фолиант {
    fn обзор(&self) -> String {
        "Класс!".to_string()
    }
}
impl Рекомендация for Фолиант {
    fn рекомендация(&self) -> String {
        "Точно читать.".to_string()
    }
}

// ВАЖНО! Просто соответствовать способности `ОбзорДляЦенителей` не достаточно, необходимы и `Обзор` и `Рекомендация` (выше) 
impl ОбзорДляЦенителей for Фолиант {
    fn ценный_обзор(&self) -> String {
        "что-то интересное и очень ценное...".to_string()
    }
}

fn напечатать_ценный_обзор(a: &dyn ОбзорДляЦенителей) {
    println!("{}", a.ценный_обзор());
}
```

И в главной функции:

```
let фолинат = Фолиант {};
напечатать_обзор(&фолинат);
напечатать_ценный_обзор(&фолинат);
```

Печатает, соответственно:

```
Класс!
что-то интересное и очень ценное...
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Пример с `ID3D12Debug5_Impl` не совсем понятен. Что делает этот код? Что мы суммируем?

Comment: `trait ID3D12Debug5_Impl` это так называемый "super trait", "сверхспособность".  Мы суммируем "способности", говорим что вот, есть что-то новое, но оно зависит от такого-то набора других "способностей".

Answer (score -1):

trait - это типа абстрактного класса, но только без полей, только методы (в том числе "абстрактные").